# Multinomial regression for modelling change of proportional makeup

Tags: r, regression, distributions, proportion, multinomial-logit

I’m reaching the limits of my statistical understanding here when it comes to model specification in BRMS. I’m a PhD student researching how different drivers of species distribution (generalised into three categories, Biotic, Environmental and Space) change across scale (e.g. from 1km up to 10km).To do this I have run some Joint Species Distribution Models and partitioned the variance in my models to understand the variance contribution of each category across my resolutions.

According to ecological theory, I should be expecting to see the variance attributed to Environment increase as scale increases, and Biotic (potential species interactions) decrease as scale increases. A visual snapshot for three of my species (15 species in total) for my data is below.

[image]

My first attempt was running three separate Beta regression models for each of these groupings to understand the impact of scale. Prevalence of the species across the resolutions is included as a quadratic because of some underlying ecological theory to do with species detection, and species are included as a random effect because I just want to know the average effect of scale.

```
Env ~ Resolution + I(prevelance^2) + (1|Species)

Bio ~ Resolution + I(prevelance^2) + (1|Species)

Spa ~ Resolution + I(prevelance^2) + (1|Species)
```

After discussion with some colleagues they were certain I should be running a multinomial version because the the proportion of variance attributed to each of my categories is not independent of one another. As below in BRMS syntax.

```
Group[Env, Bio, Spa] ~ Variance + Resolution + I(prevelance^2) + (1|Species)

fit_multinomial <- brm(Group ~ Variance + Resolution + I(prevelance^2) + (1|Species),
             data = multinomial_variance_data,
             family = categorical(link = "logit"),
             # prior = c(prior(normal(0, 1), class = "b")),
             chains = 4,
             cores = 4, 
             backend = "cmdstanr")
```

Which of these two is the more sensible approach? I have a feeling that the categorical approach is more akin to predicting the probability of something being a certain category, rather than the proportional make up of that category. Happy to be redirected towards an already answered question, but my initial searches and terminology might not be capturing the nature of my question properly here.